# Simple way to include browser dimensions in request (Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, flask

I would like to have the user's browser dimensions come through on each request. I tried having a global javascript snippet that would put it in the cookie, but that seemed to only work every other request for some reason.

It looks like this is setting the cookie after a page has loaded, in effect getting the cookie ready for the next request. This would kind of work, but as I mentioned it only works every other time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var browser_width = jQuery(window).width();
    document.cookie = 'width=' + browser_width;
    console.log()
});
```

Is there a way to reliably provide the server (`Flask`, `uwsgi`) the dimensions on each request? I understand how getting dimensions the very first time the user visits the domain may be tricky, but you guys are smarter than I am.

(from the second request on would probably be ok if that's the reality)

Comment: why do you want to do this? for browser resizing? if so look at CSS media queries.  Or are you trying to redirect to a mobile site?

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I have some widgit layouts that would greatly benefit from knowing how much space there is to work with. These layouts are constructed on the server before being handed back to the browser, so the css media queries wont help me (I don't think)

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You must rethink your layout if you need this information.